# NullException when using model and httppostedfilebase in Entity Framework and ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Here is my model

```
public ActionResult Create(CONTENTTABLE cONTENTTABLE, HttpPostedFileBase contentfile)
{
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            string path = Server.MapPath("/UserContentFiles/");

            if (!Directory.Exists(path))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
            }

            contentfile.SaveAs(path + Path.GetFileName(contentfile.FileName));
            cONTENTTABLE.CONTENTFILEPATH = path + Path.GetFileName(contentfile.FileName).ToString();

            db.CONTENTTABLEs.Add(cONTENTTABLE);
            db.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
}
```

and here is my view

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "CONTENTTABLEs", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" })) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>CONTENTTABLE</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        //another input group

        <div class="form-group">
            <label>FILE</label>
            <input type="file" name="CONTENTFILEPATH" id="CONTENTFILEPATH" class="form-control" />
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CONTENTFILEPATH, "", new { @class = "" })
        </div>

        //another input group

        <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
    </div>
}
```

And here is my model

```
public string CONTENTFILEPATH { get; set; }
//public HttpPostedFileBase CONTENTFILEPATH2 { get; set; }
```

But when executing upload, I get an error

> NullReference not handled by user code

at the controller line of code:

```
contentfile.SaveAs(path + Path.GetFileName(contentfile.FileName));
```

It looks like `contentfile` is empty :(

I've been trying many ways, ex changing model so the model now is including httppostfile base, but it still does not solve the problem. also another else.

Can you give me some reference maybe?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your method to this

```
public ActionResult Create(CONTENTTABLE cONTENTTABLE, HttpPostedFileBase CONTENTFILEPATH)
```

Answer (score 0):

By this way ,your problem will fixed

Changed Model as

```
 public HttpPostedFileBase CONTENTFILEPATH { get; set; }
```

You will need to import the following namespace.

```
 using System.IO;
```

and in your controller

```
  [HttpPost]
  public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase contentfile)
   {
      if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        string path = Server.MapPath("~/UserContentFiles/");

        if (!Directory.Exists(path))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
        }

        if (contentfile != null)
       {
         string fileName = Path.GetFileName(contentfile.FileName);
         contentfile.SaveAs(path + fileName);

         CONTENTTABLE cONTENTTABLE=new CONTENTTABLE();
         cONTENTTABLE.CONTENTFILEPATH = path + fileName

        db.CONTENTTABLEs.Add(cONTENTTABLE);
        db.SaveChanges();
      }
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
```